# highlight text which match from beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have to highlight text. I have written small code which is even highlighting the text which is not start with given value. So Is there any `RegExp` which serve the purpose of my query. I have tried `new RegExp('(^| )' + val, 'gi')` but it is removing the text. here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uyg9wqm/1/)

```js
var text= 'lu'
$('ul li').each(function(){
 var reg = new RegExp('(' + text + ')', 'gi')
txt = $(this).text();      
txt = txt.replace(reg, "<span class='highlight'>" + '$1' + "</span>");              
$(this).html(txt);                                 
})
```

```css
.highlight{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>blue diamond</li>
    <li>blue diamond lue gold</li>
    <li>lue diamond lue gold</li>
    <li>lue diamond lue</li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `\b` word boundary special character. Change your regex to this and it will do what you want:

`var reg = new RegExp('\\b(' + text + ')', 'gi')`

Comment: @amit this would do something in `foo:lu`

Answer (score 1):

You should use word boundaries to avoid matching partial words:

```
var reg = new RegExp('(\\b' + text + '\\b)', 'gi');
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uyg9wqm/9/)

Comment: when I type "lue go". it is not highlighting the text . http://jsfiddle.net/1uyg9wqm/25/

Comment: Yes that is because `lue go` is not a complete word. Do you really want to match partial words and highlight them? I think adding some clarification ions in question will be better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to highlights word that starts with `lu`, then you can use this regex:

```
var text= '(?:^|\\s)lu\\w*'
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1uyg9wqm/39/)**

[image]

```js
var text= '(?:^|\\s)lu\\w*'
$('ul li').each(function(){
 var reg = new RegExp('(' + text + ')', 'gi')
txt = $(this).text();      
txt = txt.replace(reg, "<span class='highlight'>" + '$1' + "</span>");              
$(this).html(txt);                                 
})
```

```css
.highlight{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>blue diamond</li>
    <li>blue diamond lue gold</li>
    <li>lue diamond lue gold</li>
    <li>lue diamond lue</li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just capture also the preceding space and refer the group which captures the space character in the replacement part.

```
var reg = new RegExp('(^| )(' + text + ')', 'gim')
txt = txt.replace(reg, "$1" + "<span class='highlight'>" + '$2' + "</span>");
```

**Example:**

```js
var text= 'lu'
$('ul li').each(function(){
 var reg = new RegExp('(^| )(' + text + ')', 'gim')
txt = $(this).text();      
txt = txt.replace(reg, "$1" + "<span class='highlight'>" + '$2' + "</span>");              
$(this).html(txt);                                 
})
```

```css
.highlight{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>blue diamond</li>
    <li>blue diamond lue gold</li>
    <li>lue diamond lue gold</li>
    <li>lue diamond lue</li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: check my edit.. @amit you forget to refer the first captured group in the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

I understood, that you want a RegEx, thats matches everything BUT the start.

So matching for "est":

`Test` would match

`est` wouldn't match, because it is right at the start.

If I understood it right, than following line should help:

```
var reg = new RegExp('^([^'+text+'](' + text + '))', 'gi');
```

If I missunderstood, please comment and leave it here. Maybe some day, someone finds back here and this could be the solution he/she was looking for.

Fiddle(sticks): http://jsfiddle.net/1uyg9wqm/38/